# C# FileUpload with client feedback and keep files

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a project in C# that needs to upload files in a page with a lot of others information.

**Problems**:

1 - File upload doesn't give any feedback for the user, so they can't know how long will takes (doesn't work with UploadProgress and UpdatePanel).

2 - Some validations I can't do with javascript (relationships for example), so if I get any error on the server side, FileUpload loses the file and the user needs to upload the whole file AGAIN.

3 - End user have a really poor link, so for 10mb will takes a long time (10mb is the maximum allowed).

**Solutions** (none of them works great):

1 - I can use a client side file upload with javascript (like uploadify) and get the percentage, but works as async method so I need to block the screen to don't allow the user to do another things. My worry is more about when I receive the file and save it, because I need to link this file with the other entity if not I will lose the bridge between the file and the entity. (Same happens with the AsyncFileUpload Control). This doesn't solve the problem number 2.

2 - Just do everything synchronous as FileUpload, when all the files arrive to the server, save the file and put all the informations that I need in HiddenFields, so if I get any error on the server side I can recover the file. The problem is that I can't give any feedback for the user while he uploads the file. This doesn't solve the problem number 1.

3 - Split all the files from the others entities (this will mess a lot the project) and upload file individually. The problem is that if I do that I need some mechanism to create the link between the file and the entity AND I can't allow to use the file more than once, so probably this will request a lot of resources to check it. This solves the problems listed but I think create another, complex for the user and a lot of new verifications for the system.

4 - Create 2 buttons, one button VALIDATE for validations on the server side (with no file uploads) and after this check, allow the user to click on the SAVE button. This doesn't solve the problem number 1.

Well, as you can see I'm thinking a lot about the problem but I can't find a really good solution. One that fits all my needs. Anyone have a idea?

PS: I have FileUploads inside repeaters as well, so the IDs are automatics.

Comment: have you looked at any of the `Ajax controls or JQuery` there are some examples online that show how to do this in regards to file upload..

Comment: Indeed I have used some of them (solution number 1), uploadify, SimpleAjaxUploader, AsyncFileUpload Control and others.. but the problem is not exactly about them, is about the architecture around it... because I need to save them altogether of the others information.